# appending array via swift 2

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, append

i have **a problem with appending an array**, you can see my code, i checked the problem's line by: self.items.append(....)
the array is not appended and stay empty.
here is my code:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  firer
//
//  Created by mike matta on 06/01/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Mikha Matta. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var showdatA: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var items:[String] = []
    var userFNAME:String = ""
    var userDOB:String = ""
    let textCellIdentifier = "TextCell"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        ///////////
        let UsersChannel = Firebase(url: "https://MYFIREBASE.firebaseio.com/users")

            UsersChannel.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in


                if let az = String?((snapshot.value.objectForKey("full_name"))! as! String) {

                    self.userFNAME = az

                }
                if let az2 = String?((snapshot.value.objectForKey("dob"))! as! String) {

                    self.userDOB = az2
                }

                print("\(self.userFNAME) - \(self.userDOB)")
                self.items.append(self.userFNAME) // heeereeee what i am trying to doooooooo


            })

       // print(self.items)





    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[row]

        return cell
    }

    // MARK:  UITableViewDelegate Methods
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        let row = indexPath.row
        print(items[row])
    }


}
```

*i tryed to put the array definition inside the viewdidload() it works...but i need it outside it (like my code)..

i tryed to put the array outside the async block too...still not appending*....any one ?

Comment: Is the line where you append to the array actually getting called?

Comment: @Techprimate this line is working fine: print("\(self.userFNAME) - \(self.userDOB)")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your code works !
The question is : 
Why do you think that your array is still empty ? 
You have to think the order that your instructions are executed. 
At this line :

`// print(self.items);`

Your array is still empty because the closure is not yet called. 
Put this line just after the append and you will see.

**And, Just add  `self.tableView.reloadData()`** after your append and you will be happy :) 
(It will say to your tableview to recall the delegate methods (numberOfRowsInSection ...) )